# like in mysql connector/python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using mysql-connector/python for the first time and I am facing an error.
I want to fetch the email addresses with `net` from a mysql table called `blah`.

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
p = "net"
query = ("SELECT * FROM blah WHERE email LIKE %s limit 10", ("%" + p + "%",))
cursor.execute(query,(p,))
for row in cursor:
    print row
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

and I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 491, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 683, in cmd_query
    statement))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 601, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM blah WHERE email LIKE %s limit 10", ("%" + p +"%")' at line 1
```

Can anyone suggest why is the code not working? It is working on sql -

```
select * from blah where email LIKE "%net" limit 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first argument to `cursor.execute` should be a string it looks like you have munged assigning the string and calling the function.  Probably should look something like:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE email LIKE %s limit 10"
cursor.execute(query,("%" + p + "%",))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%') limit 10"
cursor.execute(query,(p,))
```

You need to leave `%s` in the string so that MySQL Connector can substitute the `execute` parameter for it. You were setting `query` to a list, not a string.